# Are the Amp and coulomb equivalent?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, charge, units

1 coulomb is 1 ampere per second and 1 ampere is 1 coulomb per second therefore they are always equivalent. They would only be different if you changed the time but the units themselves are based only on the current/charge in 1 second. So how come their SI definition is not the same?

Comment: 1 Coulomb is 1 Ampere flowing for one second, which is not the same as one Ampere per second.

Comment: @Javier so in my question, should "ampere"  be replaced with "ampere-second?"

Comment: @Sigma, no Coulomb should be replaced by ampere-second

Comment: This is just wrong. If $1\text{C}$ is $1\text{A/s}$ and $1\text{A}$ is $1\text{C/s}$, then $1\text{C}$ would be the same as $1\text{C/s}^2$ which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You multiply current and time to get charge. So, a coulomb is equal to one amp-second, not one amp per second, which would be division. It's the same as multiplying speed and time to get distance. Speed is km/hr, distance is (km/hr)*(hr), speed times time, which is distance.

Comment: To be sure, the product of current and time has *dimension* of charge but it isn't the case that it *is* charge.  Similarly, the product of speed and time gives *dimension* of distance but...

Comment: Alright, who let the mathematician in here?

Answer (score -3):

1 Ampere is the "flow" of 1 Qoulomb of charge per second, or 6.25 x 10^18 electrons per second.  Now charge a 1 Farad capacitor to a potential of 1 Volt. The capacitor now holds 6.25 x 10^18 electrons, or 1 Qoulomb of charge. But they are not "flowing" (no per second component =  zero amperes).

Comment: Where in the world is charge measured in "Qoulombs"?

Comment: Arthur, a charged capacitor doesn't hold *excess* electrons does it?

Comment: Charge is the ability of a conductive surface to hold electrons. By definition, this is 1 Coulomb per 6.25 trilion-trillion (10^18) electrons.  Apply 2 volts to a 1 farad capacitor and current (electrons) will accumulate in the capacitor, until the counter voltage of the capacitor reached 2 volts. Then current (amperes) stops flowing.  At this time, there are twicw as many "coulombs" of charge contained in the capacitor or 12.5 x 10^18 electrins.